# SR latch effect which only requires one GPIO

Tags: latch

I have an [STM6821TWY6F](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/stm6821.pdf) watchdog IC for my MCU.  When the MCU gracefully goes to sleep it will disable the a watchdog to prevent unwanted wake ups.  The watchdog was designed to look for an oscillating signal from the MCU that it can't and shouldn't provide while asleep.

The disabling/enabling is done using a set/reset approach.  However, I am running out of GPIOs on my MCU and I'd like to know if I can still use this approach with just 1 gpio.  Meaning the same gpio sets and resets my latch?

Comment: Can I ask what watchdog IC you have?

Comment: Using this IC: STM6821TWY6F

Comment: @Feynman137 The datasheet says, *"The watchdog function may be disabled by floating WDI or tristating the driver connected to WDI."* Why not tristate your I/O pin before going to sleep?

Comment: "a set/reset approach" -- what do you currently have?  I'm not clear about how it uses more than one pin?  A diagram would be great!

Comment: @jonk i do remember reading this.  I think this is a good idea actually.  I need to make sure i can float the pin though

Comment: @Feynman137 MCUs may include the ability to tri-state their outputs while keeping them an output. Another option, which may be easier, is to consider switching it to an input, instead, before going to sleep.

Comment: @jonk excellent idea, will try this

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like a T-FF. Tie "T input" to logic high so every time there is a rising edge on GPIO, the output toggles. Would have to ensure the output starts up in a known state, and can keep track of if Q is high or low in software.

Every time GPIO '0' -> '1', xor a bit that keeps track of output state.

[image]